# Insert data into SQL Server database using C#

Tags: c#, sql-server

I am trying to make some inserts into my database. I check if my connection works and it does. But when I do the inserts, the database is always empty. What could I be doing wrong?

I have checked if the command is incorrect, but if I try it in the database it works fine.

This is my code:

```
// method to check the connection 
private bool checkConn()
{
    SqlConnection conexion = null;

    string connString = @"Data Source=desarrollo;Initial Catalog=gdo;User ID=gdo;Password=gdo21"; 
    // ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["Interface_Usuario.Properties.Settings.CS_CPP_0713ConnectionString"].ConnectionString;
    conexion = new SqlConnection(connString);

    try
    {
        conexion.Open();
        return true;
    }
    catch (SqlException)
    {
        return false;
    }
}

private void operation() 
{
    //... some operations
    bool chk = checkConn();
    System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("La conexión se ha abierto?: " + chk);

    string strsql;
    SqlConnection conexion = null;
    string connString = @"Data Source=desarrollo;Initial Catalog=gdo;User ID=gdo;Password=gdo21";

    SqlCommand comando = null;
    SqlDataAdapter adapter;

    for (int i = 0; i < lcodigo.Count; i++)
    {
        // try
        // {
        conexion = new SqlConnection(connString);
        conexion.Open();

        strsql = "";
        strsql = strsql + " INSERT INTO [gdo].[dbd].[1Volcar1]";
        strsql = strsql + " VALUES ('" + lcodigo[i] + "', '" + lsuperficie[i] + "');";

        System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(" La query que se va a hacer es: " + strsql);
        comando = new SqlCommand(strsql, conexion);
        adapter = new SqlDataAdapter(comando);
        //table = new DataTable();

        /*comando.CommandText = strsql;
        table.Columns.Clear();
        table.Clear();
        adapter.Fill(table);*/

        conexion.Close();
        /* }
        catch
        {
            if (conexion.State == ConnectionState.Open)
                conexion.Close();
            MessageBox.Show("ERROR");
        }*/
    }
}
```

Comment: did you tried somthing obvious like `SqlCommend.ExecuteNonQuery` call?

Comment: I don't think you want to use a `SQLDataAdapter` here since you aren't retrieving anything back from the database using your command. Just a simple `comando.ExecuteNonQuery();` should suffice. That being said, you really should parameterize your query instead of concatenating your variables directly into it. It might solve other errors not popping yet. [See here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.sqlclient.sqlcommand?view=netframework-4.8) for an example using `cmd.Parameters`.

Comment: [SQL Injection alert](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms161953%28v=sql.105%29.aspx) - you should **not** concatenate together your SQL statements - use **parametrized queries** instead to avoid SQL injection - check out [Little Bobby Tables](http://bobby-tables.com/)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have serious sql Injection issues. In any case you must call `ExecuteNonQuery()`. Try like:

```
strsql = " INSERT INTO [gdo].[dbd].[1Volcar1] VALUES (@param1,@param2);";
comando = new SqlCommand(strsql, conexion);
comando.Parameters.Add("@param1",SqlDbType.NVarchar).Value = lcodigo[i];
comando.Parameters.Add("@param2",SqlDbType.NVarchar).Value = lsuperficie[i];
comando.ExectuNonQuery():
```

Comment: Thank you, this works. But if I prefer to do a Select, how can I know if this select contains data or is null?

Answer (score 2):

You have to use

```
comando.ExecuteNonQuery();
```

The `SqlDataAdapter` is used the fill the dataset or the datatable used for fetch the data from the database. `ExecuteNonQuery()` just executes the query.

`ExecuteNonQuery` is used for executing queries that do not return any data (`INSERT`, `DELETE`, `UPDATE`).

Answer (score 1):

You need to perform an execute action after you prepare your query. e.g.[SqlCommand.ExecuteNonQuery](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.sqlclient.sqlcommand.executenonquery?view=netframework-4.8).

```
System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(" La query que se va a hacer es: " + strsql);
comando = new SqlCommand(strsql, conexion);
comando.ExecuteNonQuery();
```

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.sqlclient.sqlcommand.executenonquery?view=netframework-4.8